# wp_list_pages adding title to LI class

Tags: wordpress

is there a way to add the Link page title to the LI class?  I am trying to generate the navigation using wp_list_pages and would like each link to have its page title in the LI class next to page-item.  I have to style each li individually for background image hover.

Been searching but no luck =(

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. However, it does auto inject the unique `page-id` into the class. Per the documementation for [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)

> All list items (li) generated by
>   wp_list_pages() are marked with the
>   class page_item. When wp_list_pages()
>   is called while displaying a Page, the
>   list item for that Page is given the
>   additional class current_page_item.

It is possible use a [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) for `wp_list_pages()` which may allow you to do what you want. But that may be overkill. I think the page-id should cut it.

Comment: the only issue is if the pages change then the id changes, i was attempting to find a way to have each class be name specific so if the id number changes the classes doesnt have to be renamed.

Comment: I understand. It's a common issue I have too. But once you make the page the id won't change. In the end, it's never been worth the time to be more invasive. To be fair, page title is more likely to change than the id.

Comment: truth! Thanks for the insight.